# How long does it take for an iOS app to recognize a DNS change?

Tags: ios, dns

I recently changed the DNS records for a domain name to point to a new IP. An iPhone app of mine that pings this domain doesn't seem to be picking up the change, although my desktop web browser quickly picked up the new IP. How long does it take for an iPhone to flush its DNS cache for a particular domain and detect that the DNS records have changed?

Comment: What's the TTL on the DNS record?

Comment: Step1 in a DNS change is first to lower the TTL (1 hour or so). Step2:  wait until the original TTL has passed. Step3: change the IP address of the DNS record.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had this problem I just did two steps:

Step 1 - Turn off iPhone

Step 2 - Turn on Phone, Reload page.

Otherwise I've read it takes about 24 hours for a DNS refresh to occur on the iPhone.

Comment: could you pls share me the the document related the above statement

Answer (score 3):

To flush the DNS cache on an iOS device, switch it to "Airplane Mode" and then back again.

Comment: This doesn't force any DNS cache refresh, as such does not work. It doesn't actually answer the question either.

Comment: This did actually flush a DNS cache issue I was having just now. Cheers. Using Safari in iOS 11. Not sure if it applies to other custom iOS apps though.

Answer (score 1):

Airplane mode, Shut Down and restart, Hard restart; does not seem to always work, especially on the wifi connection's cached IP tables. The only method that I have found, if that is the case; is to Reset the Network Settings.

Settings/General/Reset/Rest Network Settings

Only problem is that it resets ALL of your settings which means you may need to input some passwords again on your home or work WiFi networks.

Anyone on comes up with any others I would be interested to know about it.